# Monoids of endomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, monoid

Can one tell whether an (abstract) monoid $M$ is (isomorphic to) the monoid of endomorphisms of a structure $X$?

Or is there a representation theorem saying that for *every* monoid $M$ there is a structure $X$ such that $M$ is the monoid of endomorphisms of $X$? If not so: what is a simple counter-example?

How can the monoids which *are* monoids of endomorphisms be characterized?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cayley's theorem for monoids asserts that $M$ is isomorphic to the monoid of endomorphisms of $M$ as a right $M$-set. This argument can be internalized to various categories; for example, a ring $R$ is isomorphic to the ring of endomorphisms of $R$ as a right $R$-module.

Comment: Could you please give me a link to Cayley's theorem for monoids? It's not so easily to be found.

Comment: I don't know a reference where it's stated explicitly, but it's a straightforward exercise. The proof is exactly the same as for groups; you don't use inversion anywhere.

Comment: @HansStricker I am pretty sure it appears in Jacobson's *Basic Algebra I*. I think he was pretty meticulous about putting in all versions of Cayley's theorem. Can't find it in the googlebooks preview, but if I remember I'll check again when I find my copy.

Comment: @rschwieb: Thanks for the hint. I am looking forward to your finding of your copy!